# How to move close icon to the inside right side of the search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a wikipedia viewer. When you click the magnifying glass, it disappears and a search bar and close icon appear.

How do I move the close/clear icon to the inside right side of the search bar?

https://codepen.io/jenlky/pen/WZBLEL

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fa-search").click(function(){
    $(".fa-search, form").toggle();
  });
  
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #033350;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.container, .row {
  height: 90%;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
}

/* doesn't work for some reason... 
a, .fa, a:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
*/

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

form {
  display: none;
}

.searchBar {
  border: 4px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #033350;
  color: white;
}

.ion-close-round {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e879f2bf45.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"/>
<h1>Wikipedia Viewer</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <form>
        <input type="search" class="searchBar" size="20px;" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Wikipedia">
        <i class="icon ion-close-round"></i>
    </form>
    <a class="btn" target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"><i class="fa fa-random fa-3x" title="Random article" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its already in the right of search bar. Do you want inside search bar???

Comment: yes to the right of the inside of the search bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file. Making the close button a position absolute allows for the element to float on top of the search field and setting the form to position relative constraints the top and right values of the close button. Also adding a padding-right to the .searchBar allows the entered text to not overflow over the close icon.

```
form {
    position: relative;
}
.ion-close-round {
    position: absolute;
    color: orange;
    right: 15px;
    top: 7px;
}
.searchBar {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: when I type many words in the search bar, the close icon appears on top of the words and cover it. How do I make it so the clear icon wouldn't cover the words?? should i change the display, or what should I do?

Comment: by adding a padding-right to the .searchBar element